# Mocking helper class with Mockito

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

I have a plain helper class with public methods which I am using in the service level class. When I am writing test for the service class and trying to mock this helper class for one of the method it is going inside the methods and running every line. Since code inside this method is more complex I want to mock helper class with method(s) so that I don't have to take care of every detail inside helper class method.

Service Class

```
class HistoryServiceImpl implements CaseHistory {
  @Override
  public List<CaseHistoryDto> getCaseHistory(Individual member, Individual provider) {
    MemberUtil memberUtil = new MemberUtil();
    List<CaseHistoryDto> caseHistoryDtoList = new ArrayList<CaseHistoryDto>();
    List<CaseHistory> caseHistoryList = caseDetailDao.fetchCaseHistory(member.getId(), provider.getId());
    for(CaseHistory caseHistory : caseHistoryList) {
        CaseHistoryDto caseHistoryDto = new CaseHistoryDto();
        caseHistoryDto.setMemberInfo(memberUtil.getMemberInfo(member, caseHistory.getCreateDate()));
        caseHistoryDtoList.add(caseHistoryDto);
    }
    return caseHistoryDtoList;
  }
}
```

Test Class

```
Class HistoryServiceTest {
  @Mock MemberUtil memberUtil;
  @InjectMocks private HistoryServiceImpl historyServiceImpl = new HistoryServiceImpl();

  @Test
  public void testGetCaseHistory() {
    //why this line going inside real method and executing all lines?
    when(memberUtil.getMemberInfo(any(Individual.class), any(Date.class))).thenReturn(member);
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason that your test case is running all the lines in the "real" method, is because your mock object is never being used anywhere.

As written, you cannot mock `MemberUtil` in your `HistoryServiceImpl`, because you are manually instantiating it in the `getCaseHistory()` method.  You need to make `getCaseHistory()` get its `MemberUtil` from somewhere else, so that you can inject your mock version in your test class.

The simplest solution would be to define your `MemberUtil` as a member variable, so that the [`@InjectMocks`](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/1.9.5/org/mockito/InjectMocks.html) annotation can override the default value:

```
class HistoryServiceImpl implements CaseHistory {
    MemberUtil memberUtil = new MemberUtil();

    @Override
    public List<CaseHistoryDto> getCaseHistory(Individual member, Individual provider) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Alternately you could have `HistoryServiceImpl` accept an externally provided `MemberUtil`, either in its constructor or via a setter method.  You can then easily pass in a mocked version in your test class.

Generally, utility classes are stateless, so another possible solution would be to convert `MemberUtil` to make all of its methods static.  Then you can use something like [PowerMock](http://code.google.com/p/powermock/) to mock your static methods.

Comment: It doesn't need to be in a constructor or setter method.  The @InjectMocks annotation can set private fields; so all you need is a field of type `MemberUtil`, and this will work as you expect.

Comment: @DavidWallace Ah, you're right, that's even simpler.  I'll update my answer.